# I want to get a certain part of a google maps div, but it isn't showing up on selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking to access this div in selenium:

```
<div jstcache="829" class="section-editorial-quote section-editorial-divider" jsan="t-6URMd4sqjIY,7.section-editorial-quote,7.section-editorial-divider,t-1Oo3GrRI6AU"> <span jstcache="827">Branch of a family-friendly chain offering pizzas, salads &amp; wings, plus a gluten-free menu.</span> </div>
```

Originally I just tried to search the contents of the the webpage for "section-editorial-quote section-editorial-divider". This selenium code isn't working either. Am I not, running the JavaScript Dom properly?

```
// Other code missing

    const url = "random google maps restaurant";

    await driver.get(url);
    await driver.wait (
      until.elementLocated (
        By.className (
             "section-editorial-quote section-editorial-divider"
       )
      )
    );
    await driver.findElement(
      By.className("section-editorial-quote section-editorial-divider")
    );
```

Comment: can you please try this :  await driver.findElement(
      By.cssSelector(".section-editorial-quote.section-editorial-divider")

Comment: @SelçukAyhan this didn't work, it gave me this error`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: section-editorial-quote section-editorial-divider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using

```
By.className ("section-editorial-quote section-editorial-divider")
```

Use

```
By.css("div[class='section-editorial-quote section-editorial-divider']")
```